# Chromedriver: session deleted because of page crash

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, protractor, selenium-chromedriver, ng-file-upload

I am writing tests for my AngularJS application using **protractor** and **jasmine**.

I am testing file upload case using the code below:

```
const fileElem = element(by.css('input[type="file"]'));

fileElem.sendKeys(absoluteFilePath);

browser.sleep(500);
```

It **works locally** with the next packages:

```
"chromedriver": "2.38.2", "protractor": "5.3.1", Chrome - v.66.0.3359.139
```

But when I run this tests on GitLab CI, I get an error:

> [chrome #01] F    ✗ should upload the file
>
> [chrome #01]       - Failed: unknown error: session deleted because of
>   page crash
>
> [chrome #01]       from unknown error: cannot determine loading status
>
> [chrome #01]       from tab crashed
>
> [chrome #01]         (Session info: headless chrome=65.0.3325.181)
>
> [chrome #01]         (Driver info: chromedriver=2.38.552522 
>   (437e6fbedfa8762dec75e2c5b3ddb86763dc9dcb),platform=Linux
>   4.13.5-coreos-r2 x86_64)

I am using **ng-file-upload** directive.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Your given code not includes the part to click submit start uploading, So does the issue come from this line: `fileElem.sendKeys(absoluteFilePath`,  or during uploading process?

Comment: @yong it uploads a file on model change. So in this line: `fileElem.sendKeys(absoluteFilePath);` It changes the model and uploads the file. It works fine locally.

Comment: Does the uploaded file also exist on remote machine?

Comment: The file is in a folder with the project. It exists on the remote machine.

Comment: I guess you will meet same issue whatever file you choose to upload, you can try and prove my guess. If so I can get the root cause.

Comment: I can tell you my guess on root cause.  When enter the file path via `sendKeys`,  the model will detect change when each char be entered. So if the file path length is 10, the model will detect 10 times change. Each time model change will trigger file upload.  But the file path of the first 9 times are incorrect and so frequent file uploading lead to browser crash.

Answer (score 2):

i had the same problem while running selenium on my vps. After 5 hours i found that, too much unclosed process try to use the driver. try ti kill them all

```
pkill -f chrome*
```

Answer (score 0):

`sendKeys` enter string char by char, the model will detect change when each char be entered. So if the file path has 10 chars, the model will detect 10 times change. Each time model change will trigger file upload. But the file path of the first 9 times are incorrect and so frequent file uploading lead to browser crash.

```
const fileElem = element(by.css('input[type="file"]'));

// input file path by javascript in silent to avoid multiple model change
browser.executeScript(
   'arguments[0].value=arguments[1];',
   fileElem.getWebElement(),
   absoluteFilePath 
);

// input a blank space at the end of file path 
// to let model detect change, then trigger file uploading.
fileElem.sendKeys(" ");
```

Comment: It doesn't work. We can't set `<input type="file">` from `javascript`.